# Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2 Macbook M1: zsh: bad CPU type in executable: adb

Tags: android, android-studio

I have install Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2 on Macbook M1,
I am able to open it and run the emulator

However when i run adb command i got an error `zsh: bad CPU type in executable: adb`

if i run `file ${which adb)` i got output `/Users/my_user/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb: Mach-0 64-bit executable x86_64`

How to install native adb command for M1?

Answer (score 0):

As [Daan says in his blog](https://linuxpip.org/fix-bad-cpu-type-in-executable/), you should install Rosetta 2. Open the terminal and paste this:

```
/usr/sbin/softwareupdate --install-rosetta --agree-to-license
```

That worked for me :)